# How to display payment method to logged in user only?

Tags: magento, payment-method

display payment method to logged in user only in magneto.
As in screenshot enter code here i want to display credit card(saved) to logged in user only.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Possibe duplicate, this might help :

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33047/displaying-certain-payment-methods-for-customer-groups

Comment: i just want to dispaly credit card(saved) method to logged in user only.

Comment: How to create a group of logged in user?

Comment: If user is not logged in no need to show credit card option right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function to check if user is logged in or not

```
$userLogStatus = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
```

You can put in the condition for credit card(saved).
You can do this int the template file itself.
[Pseudo code]

```
if(payment==cc-saved){
 if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
   show option;
 }
}
```

Comment: thanx anz for idea. The actual i added in public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml is <?php if(($_code==ccsave) && (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())):?>
<?php continue; ?>
<?php endif; ?>